# Stored procedure says command completed successfully but does't actually do anything

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Sorry for the poor title, wasn't exactly sure how to word it.

I have been trying to implement the `HASHBYTES` function in SQL Server to encrypt passwords. I used this [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/) as a template to help me with this as I felt it was quite detailed.

I made this procedure to create my new user;

```
create proc AddUser
    @User_Name nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50),
    @Organisation_ID int,
    @Email nvarchar(254) = null,
    @Phone nvarchar(15) = null,
    @AllowPMR bit,
    @CCAddress nvarchar(254) = null,
    @Active_User bit,
    @responseMessage nvarchar(250) output
as
begin
    set nocount on
    declare @Salt uniqueidentifier=newid()
    begin try
        insert into dbo.[Users]
            (User_ID,User_Name,Password,Organisation_ID,Email,Phone,AllowPMR,PWDChanged,CCAddress,Active_User,Salt)
        values((select max(USER_ID) from Users)+1,@User_Name,HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@Password+cast(@Salt as nvarchar(36))),@Organisation_ID,@Email,@Phone,@AllowPMR,GETDATE(),@CCAddress,@Active_User,@Salt)

        set @responseMessage='Success'
    end try
    begin catch
        set @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()
    end catch
end
```

And then I execute the `AddUser` stored procedure like so;

```
DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)

exec Adduser
    @User_Name = 'username',
    @Password = 'passwords?lol',
    @Organisation_ID = 1,
    @AllowPMR = 1,
    @Active_User = 1,
    @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT
```

this returns

> Command(s) completed successfully.

but when I check whats in my users table nothing has been added. Have I misread the tutorial, or is something wrong with my query?

Comment: Did you check the `@responseMessage`?

Comment: Unrelated but `select max(USER_ID) from Users)+1` is not the way to do this, what happens if the query runs in parallel?  Use an `identity` column and the DB will take care of this for you.

Comment: @AlexK. i didnt create the database, person who made it didnt set up the identity and the table is difficult to drop and recreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `try`/`catch` block.  If the `insert` is failing for some reason, then you are catching the error.  However, you are not doing anything with it, so the stored procedure will succeed.  You could also print the error message after you run the procedure.  Removing the exception handling is more dramatic.

The construct `(select max(USER_ID) from Users)+1` is also suspicious.  You should simply define `user_id` to be an `identity` column, and let the database do the incrementing for you.

Comment: i took the `try catch` out and it when i ran it i realised that its because im using a copy of the table as a test table to not mess up the original and because my `(select max(USER_ID) from Users)+1` was returning null thats why it wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

you can also use rowcount function beneath insert statement if insert failing without any error,

```
    if(@@ROWCOUNT<=0)
    BEGIN
      set @responseMessage='Insert fail'
    END
```